# Countable sum of closed boundary sets

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I have to prove that for complete metric space and $f_n$ converge pointwisely to $f$
 $f^{-1}(a,b)\setminus Int(f^{-1} (a,b))  $ is countable sum of closed, boundary sets. 
Here is my solution:
$f^{-1}  ((a,b))={x:a<f(x)<b}={x: ∃ n\in N  a+1/n  ≤f(x)≤b-1/n} =    
{x: ∃ n∈N,∃ m∈M ∀_{(k>m)}  a+1/n  ≤f_k (x)≤b-1/n}=  $
$⋃_{(n,m)}⋂_{(k≥m)} f_k^{-1} ([a+1/n,b-1/n]) $ It is a countable sum of closed boundary sets. 
But I am not sure if I can do it this way, if yes/no can you tell me why ?

Comment: $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$, instead

Comment: yes, my mistake

Comment: $f^{-1}(a,b)$ is a subset, not an element

Comment: You should have said that $f_n$ are continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the right idea, but the solution may be incomplete. I suppose that "closed boundary set" means "closed bounded set". But there is no reason for the set $f_k^{-1} ([a+1/n,b-1/n])$ to be bounded.

For better readability, I would separate the proof into three steps:

**Step 1:** $f^{-1}(a,b)$ is a countable union of closed sets. This is what you already did: $$f^{-1}(a,b) = \bigcup_{m,n}\bigcap_{k\ge m}f_k^{-1} ([a+1/n,b-1/n])$$  **Step 2:** $f^{-1}(a,b)$ is a countable union of closed bounded sets. This follows by fixing a point $x$  in the domain of $f$ and taking intersections with closed balls $\overline{B}(x,r)$ over $r=1,2,3,\dots$
$$f^{-1}(a,b) = \bigcup_{m,n,r}\left(\overline B(x,r)\cap \bigcap_{k\ge m}f_k^{-1} ([a+1/n,b-1/n])\right)$$ **Step 3:** $f^{-1}(a,b)\setminus \operatorname{Int}f^{-1}(a,b) $ is a countable union of closed bounded sets. For this, take the intersection with the complement of $\operatorname{Int}f^{-1}(a,b) $: 
$$\bigcup_{m,n,r}\left((\overline B(x,r)\setminus \operatorname{Int}f^{-1}(a,b))\cap \bigcap_{k\ge m}f_k^{-1} ([a+1/n,b-1/n])\right)$$