# Intuition behind this equality.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions and $f_n\rightarrow f$ almost everywhere. Then why following holds?

> $f^{-1}((a,\infty))=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\cap_{i=n}^{\infty}f_i^{-1}((a+\frac{1}{n},\infty))$

Can anyone explain why above holds in an intuitive sense?

Comment: Do you already understand one or the other direction of the equality ($\subseteq$ or $\supseteq$)?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I don't understand the both of the inequality unfortunately...

Comment: not sure but [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2959701/if-a-sequence-of-measurable-functions-f-n-converge-to-f-almost-everywhere) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651329/countable-sum-of-closed-boundary-sets) should help